# Pycord - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'created_at'

Tags: python, discord, bots, pycord

I am trying to make a user info command it worked well with the prefix, but when i convert it to a slash command i got this error
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'created_at'`
Here is the code:

```
@bot.slash_command(name="info", description="Get information about a user", guild_ids=[824342611774144543])
async def info(ctx, user:discord.Member=None):
    if user==None:
        user=ctx.author

    embedinfo = discord.Embed(color=0x774dea, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
    embedinfo.set_author(name=f"User Info | {user}"),
    embedinfo.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar.url),
    embedinfo.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar.url)

    embedinfo.add_field(name='Username:', value=user.display_name, inline=True)
    embedinfo.add_field(name='Top Role:', value=user.top_role.mention, inline=True)
    embedinfo.add_field(name='\u200b', value='\u200b', inline=True)

    embedinfo.add_field(name='Created at:', value=user.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y, %T"), inline=True)
    embedinfo.add_field(name='Joined at:', value=user.joined_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y, %T"), inline=True)

    embedinfo.add_field(name='ID:', value=user.id, inline=False)

    await ctx.respond(embed=embedinfo)
```

Full Error:

```
Ignoring exception in command info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 110, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(arg)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 774, in _invoke
    await self.callback(ctx, **kwargs)
  File "e:\HypePartyBOT\test5.py", line 792, in info
    embedinfo = discord.Embed(color=0x774dea, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'created_at'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\bot.py", line 768, in process_application_commands
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 306, in invoke
    await injected(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 116, in wrapped
    raise ApplicationCommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.commands.errors.ApplicationCommandInvokeError: Application Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'created_at'
```

Comment: You're making us guess where the error happens.  Please update the question to include the full error message traceback.

Comment: @JohnGordon, There you go hope that helps

Comment: The error is because `ctx.message` is None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the timestamp to `timestamp=datetime.utcnow())` instead of `timestamp=ctx.message.created_at` and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `if user is None:` instead of `==None:`.

Comment: It didnt work, same error